# Atleast two different condition in where clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need sql for CC order for which conditions are as below:

1. order is G If at least one order line has HAZ = Y
2. order is CC If at least one order line has UD = Y and atleast one of the line has HAZ = Y

**for order G sql is as below:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT oh.order_id 
FROM order oh, order ol 
WHERE oh.order_id = ol.order_id
AND ol.sku_id IN (SELECT sku_id FROM dcsdba.sku WHERE haz = 'Y' AND client_id = 'C')
AND oh.client_id = 'C';
```

Comment: Sample data would help your question.

Comment: I have orders A. order A have two lines C and D. C have HAZ = Y and D have UD =Y. so atleast one of lines C and D have both condition true so this order should be select as CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your conditions correctly, the query should be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_id
  FROM orders ords
 WHERE client_id = 'C'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM dcsdba.sku
                WHERE haz       = 'Y' 
                  AND client_id = 'C'
                  AND sku_id    = ords.sku_id)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM dcsdba.sku
                WHERE ud        = 'Y' 
                  AND client_id = 'C'
                  AND sku_id    = ords.sku_id);
```

what you should be utilizing is the `EXISTS` clause.